# Tkinter Grid System

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

```
title = Label (root, text = "Expectancy Calculator")
title.grid(row = 0, column = 2)

howManyStocksLabel = Label(root, text = "How many stocks do you want to evaluate?")
howManyStocksLabel.grid(row = 1, column = 0)
howManyStocksEntry = Entry(root, borderwidth = 3)
howManyStocksEntry.grid(row = 1, column = 1)


riskLabel = Label(root, text = "Enter risk %                                                        ")
riskLabel.grid(row = 2, column = 0)
riskEntry = Entry(root, borderwidth = 3)
riskEntry.grid(row = 2, column = 1)

isChnaceDefaultCheckButton = Checkbutton(root, text = "Make chance = 0.9?")
isChnaceDefaultCheckButton.grid(row = 3, column = 0)

nextButton = Button(root, text = "Next!", fg = 'green', bg = 'white',
                    command= lambda: myClick(riskEntry, howManyStocksEntry))
nextButton.grid(row = 4, column = 2)
```

I've got two problems here; firstly, the `riskEntryLabel` doesn't exactly start from column 0 unless I put all of these spaces after the `%`.

Here's a screenshot to the program without the spaces in `riskEntryLabel`.

[image: screenshot]

Is there any other way to solve this problem other than inserting all of these spaces? And more importantly, why does `tkinter` behave that way?

Secondly, how to put the text of the `Checkbutton` on its left not its right?

Comment: `.grid` automatically centers your widgets. You can add `sticky="w"` to the `.grid()` if you want the widget to go to the left.

Comment: I don't quite understand you. Can you demonstrate it by inserting it into my code?

Comment: look at the answer @ BryanOakley wrote. It's basically what I said but in a bit more detail

Answer (score 3):

When using `grid`, widgets will be centered in the space allocated to them. In your case, the first column is very wide due to the "How many stocks..." label.  To get the risk label aligned to the left you want it to "stick" to the left side of the space rather than being centered.

You do this with the `sticky` attribute, which can be given a compass point ("n", "s", "e", "w") or combination of points (eg: "nsew")

```
riskLabel.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky="w")
```

As for the checkbutton, it has an option named `anchor` which specifies how to align the text to the checkbutton.

```
cb = Checkbutton(root, text="Make chance = 0.9?", anchor="w")
cb.grid(row=3, column=0, sticky="ew")
```

It appears you want the checkbutton to the right of the text. The checkbutton doesn't support that. The normal way to do that is the create a checkbutton without text, and then use a label for the text exactly the same way you do the entry widgets.

Comment: The riskLabel worked fine, but the check button problem persists. The check button is still at the left side of the text.

Comment: @bewop west is on the left side btw so try changing the anchor

Comment: @bewop: The text of a `Checkbutton` is always to the right of its checkbox.

Comment: @bewop: I've updated my answer. I missed the fact that you want to checkbutton and text reversed. In short, the tk checkbutton doesn't support that. The simplest solution is to create a label and then a checkbutton without text.